# How to use .fit() with cross validation

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm pretty new to data science and a bit confused.
And just want to ensure that my approach makes sense.

I create modells like:

```
lr7 = GaussianNB().fit(X_train,y_train)
```

and using the cross_val_predict() right after.

```
y_pred8 = cross_val_predict(lr8, X_test, y_test, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=5)
```

Wouldn't it make much more sense to cross validate the train set first?

There is also a `cross_validate()`function in scikitlearn.
Is it correct to use this one with the train dataset? In the documentation they use X and y for both and not train/test splitted data.

Comment: We *never* cross-validate the *test* set.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement cross-validation is by using the  `cross_val_score` function ( from sklearn. This may be appropriate for your problem.

```
# build model
lr7 = GaussianNB()
scores = cross_val_score(lr7, X, y, cv=5)
```

Note that in cross validation you use either the whole dataset or the training part `X_train`, `y_train`, but never the test part as you show in your code.

Comment: Keeping a separate test set is not incompatible with cross validation. The important thing that should be stressed here (given what OP shows in their post) is that we never cross-validate the *test* set.

Comment: @desertnaut  Yes - fair point. What is the correct procedure here? Should I edit my answer to reflect this, or should I simply delete?

Comment: I edited myself - pls review to ensure you are happy.